# upvoting and reputation

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

I was under the impression that upvotes on an answer would yield reputation; However, I have noticed that I have received two upvotes on an answer, but I did not receive reputation. Also, I noticed that in another answer that I provided I did receive reputation from upvoting, but did not receive additional reputation after a certain amount of upvotes.

Is there a certain window of time from when the question was posted to receive reputation from upvotes, or does one only receive reputation before a certain amount of upvotes?

I have viewed other responses that seemed to yield quite a bit of rep from upvotes on SO. This is the reason I am confused. I have perused the FAQ and related posts, but I have not found the answer to my question. Clarification on how upvoting generates reputation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this? [How does reputation work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer on your Super User account was on a question which got migrated to Meta. Since your answer was deleted and migrated you lost rep on that answer.

Comment: thanks, is there a reason that my post on community promotional ads did not receive rep. How does reputation work states that upvotes give +5.

Comment: Here on Meta, you don't get any reputation, it's just inherited from the main site. @sha

Comment: I would think that I would have 1 reputation here then if it was inherited from the main site.

Comment: @ShaneKelsey the rep takes some time to sync